# If I have a fraction, such as $\frac{1}{y^{-3}}$ raised to a $1/6$-th power, do I distribute the power in the numerator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am studying Pre Calculus, and we are currently reviewing the exponent laws. I for the life of me can't figure out if the power of $1/6$ will distribute over the one. If It was the power $2, 3$ or $4$, the answer would be one, but what about the power of $1/6^{th}$?

The problem I am asked to solve is 
$$
\frac{x^{-2/3}}{y^{1 / 2}} \cdot \left( \frac{x^{-2}}{y^{-3}} \right)^{1/6}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\left(\dfrac{1}{y^{-3}}\right)^{\frac{1}{6}} = \dfrac{1^{\frac{1}{6}}}{(y^{-3})^{\frac{1}{6}}} = \dfrac{\sqrt[6]1}{y^{-\frac{3}{6}}} = \dfrac{1}{y^{-\frac{1}{2}}} = y^{\frac{1}{2}} = \sqrt{y}$

Comment: I really wanted to know why the power 1/6th does not distribute over the one since 1/6th is 0.1666. Would not raising a power by 1/6th change the value of 1? Please explain.

Comment: please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you are running into is what does it mean when a number is raised to a fractional power.

Remember that
$$
x^{1/b} := \text{A $y \in \mathbb{R}^+$ so that } x = y^b
$$
From this you can see that
$$
1^{1/6} := \text{A $y \in \mathbb{R}^+$ so that } 1 = y^6 
$$
can be solved with $y = 1$ so $1^{1/6} = 1$. Now with more complicated exponents, when you have
$$
\left( x^a y^c \right)^b = x^{a \cdot b} y^{c \cdot b}
$$
for any $a,b,x \in \mathbb{R}$. So now notice that

$$
\left( \frac{x^{-2}}{y^{-3}} \right)^{1/6} = \left( x^{-2} \cdot y^3 \right)^{1/6} = x^{- 1 / 3} y^{1 / 2} = \frac{y^{1 / 2}}{x^{1 / 3}}
$$
and then
$$
\frac{x^{-2 / 3}}{y^{1 / 2}} \cdot \left( \frac{x^{-2}}{y^{-3}} \right)^{1/6} = \frac{x^{-2 / 3}}{y^{1 / 2}} \cdot \frac{y^{1 / 2}}{x^{1 / 3}} = \frac{1}{x^{2 / 3}} \cdot \frac{1}{x^{1 / 3}} = \frac{1}{x} = x^{-1}
$$